# WHERE Clause with pattern matching to find rows with any characters NOT in a list

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am in a SQL Server 2008 environment.

I am trying to use pattern matching in the `WHERE` clause to find rows where a certain column's value contains characters that are not alpha-numeric, underscore, dash, period, or space.

This is my code, and sample data, but I am not getting the results expected.

In the example data, I want to return rows 7, 8, 9, and 12, but I am getting rows 5 and 6.

If this isn't the best way to achieve the goal, I am open to hearing other methods.

I am not in an environment where I can implement regex so my solution limited to out-of-the-box functionality.

```
CREATE TABLE PATTERN_TEST
(
ID INT NOT NULL,
STRING NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO PATTERN_TEST
SELECT 1, 'string' UNION 
SELECT 2, 'STRING' UNION 
SELECT 3, 'string space' UNION 
SELECT 4, 'STRING SPACE' UNION 
SELECT 5, 'string-dash' UNION 
SELECT 6, 'string-dash space' UNION 
SELECT 7, 'string "otherchar"' UNION 
SELECT 8, 'string "other char"' UNION 
SELECT 9, '"string"' UNION 
SELECT 10, 'string_underscore' UNION 
SELECT 11, 'string_underscore space' UNION
SELECT 12, '"'
;

SELECT * FROM PATTERN_TEST WHERE STRING LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9_ -.]%';
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will work as well:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PATTERN_TEST 
WHERE STRING LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9_ .-]%' ;
```

Tested at [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/XZCWQ69268)

The only difference is that dash (`-`) is put at the end of the `[...]` pattern. It has to do with the special meaning of the dash character (`A-Z` is interpreted as *"any character from `A` to `Z`"*).

In your pattern the last three characters (space-dash-dot: `-.`) are interpreted as *"any character from space () to dot (`.`)"*, and the results are not the wanted/expected.

You could also escape the dash:

```
WHERE STRING LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9_ $-.]%' ESCAPE '$' ;
```

Note though that using `ESCAPE` [may adversely affect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/680257/optimization-problem-on-a-query-with-two-similar-like-clauses-one-with-a-variable) cardinality estimation.

See the MSDN documentation for some details: [`LIKE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx):

> If there is no character after an escape character in the LIKE pattern, the pattern is not valid and the LIKE returns FALSE. If the character after an escape character is not a wildcard character, the escape character is discarded and the character following the escape is treated as a regular character in the pattern. This includes the percent sign (%), underscore (_), and left bracket ([) wildcard characters when they are enclosed in double brackets ([ ]). **Also, within the double bracket characters ([ ]), escape characters can be used and** the caret (^), **hyphen (-),** and right bracket (]) **can be escaped.**

To be clear: special characters need escaping when they are used as non-special. Inside [], the three (^, -, ]) are special. Putting the dash at the end is more like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Always sucks to be in a situation where you aren't able to leverage the full feature set of the tool you're asked to use.  CLRs are absolutely the way to do this correctly.

If I understand correctly, I think you should be able to write a function to return a null set when the passed string contains one of your invalid characters and use `CROSS APPLY` to strip out invalid results.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RemoveInvalidString
(
    @String         NVARCHAR( 4000 )
) RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
(
    WITH cte_InvalidCharList ( InvalidChar ) AS (
            SELECT  '"'
    UNION   SELECT  '-' )
    SELECT  IsClean = 1 
    FROM (  SELECT  1 ) dummyRecord ( dummy )
    WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT  1
                        FROM    cte_InvalidCharList rt
                        WHERE   @String LIKE '%' + rt.InvalidChar + '%' )
);
GO

SELECT  pt.ID, pt.STRING
FROM    dbo.PATTERN_TEST pt
CROSS APPLY dbo.RemoveInvalidString ( pt.STRING );
```

Comment: Yeah agreed. The crux of my question here is that the list of allowed characters is small and defined, so I don't want to have to define a set of DISallowed characters...  I think if I replace space, underscore, dash, and dot with nothing, make it all lower case, then all I would have left is a-z0-9, plus DISallowed chars... should be easy to do from there I think

Comment: Too early for reading for me, apparently!  You could also just generate the list of invalid characters by enumerating from a `sys.objects` cross apply and omitting the corresponding values from your smaller allowed list, but...  @ypercube's answer.